# display connection error messages in ionic framework

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic mobile app but getting difficulty to display the connection error message. When the device is not connected to the internet or when there is a connection timeout or something then I want to show a popup  to display the error message. This is my first time encountering something like this.

Comment: may i know how your checking for connection status??

Comment: i havent even checked for anything yet i dont know how i would go about it

Comment: well then read this  and try to implement according to the document ,am sure you can meet your requirement https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/

Comment: thanks will check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--first add the plugin to your project
then in your app.js include the below code

**js**

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

        $rootScope.online = true;
        function onOffline() {
            // Handle the offline event
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                $rootScope.online = false;
               alert("There is no active internet connection to your app. Please check the connectivity.");
               //implement your method off error when the connection terminates

            });
         }

        document.addEventListener("online", function() {
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
alert("connected");
                $rootScope.online = true;
                $rootScope.closeToast();
            });
        }, false);
```

here offile will handle the connection termination and online will handle the reconnection and check with the alerts or consoles

Comment: so the offline handles any further connection error

Comment: i mean like connection timeout and something like connection refused

Comment: in both cases you mentioned the result is no internet connection,so this will work for sure

Comment: ok thank you very much so i can easily add popup instead of alert

Comment: should it be inside my controller or the run function for ionic

Comment: yeah that's good way to show these kind of messages.have you implemented this in your project ??is it working for you?

Comment: make it in side your app.js

Comment: its still building will alert u as soon as it is done

Comment: thats  great,use md toaster if you can,its looks good than normal angular toaster

Comment: this is angular 1 not 2

Comment: k then follow those your angular version supported