# How to check for network connection in ionic app before calling factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, networking, service, ionic-framework

How to check for network connection in an ionic app everytime when a service is called or app state has changed , i have included a plugin to check the network connection and created a factory to check for network connection value

here is my factory that checks for network connection value :

```
.factory("Network", ['errorModule','$state','$ionicPopup',function(errorModule,$state,$ionicPopup) {

    return{
            isOnline : function(throwErr){
                var online = navigator.onLine;
                if(!online&&throwErr){
                   // errorModule.throwException(100,"No network connection");
                     ionicAlert($ionicPopup,'',"No network connection");
                }
                 return online;
            }
        }
    }
])
```

i want to check for network connection every time i visit a state until the full data from services gets loaded , i want to show an ionic alert with retry option and again call the service to fetch the data again if it gets internet connection , inside my controller i have checked the condition like this :

```
if(navigator.onLine){
          calldataFetchFunction();
        }else{
             var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                template: 'no internet  connection',
                buttons: [{
                text:'Ok',
                onTap: function(e) {
                    calldataFetchFunction();
                }

                }]
            });
        }
```

calldataFetchFunction(); contains code for parsing the fetched data from web services , problem i am facing here is on the click of the ok button i again call the function to parse data , as data not available my condition fails , where should i check this connection whether in services or controller , i am confused about the approach to follow and how ?

Comment: so you want to check network connection everytime ??

Comment: before calling a web service  to fetch data and then trying calling that web service again until i get a connected network popup should not  gets closed

Comment: so you want to fetch some thing when there is no connection from that alert

Comment: i want to show a popup when their is no connection , and that popup should stay until user gets connection again

Comment: then here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305800/display-connection-error-messages-in-ionic-framework/38306129#38306129

Comment: it is not working in my code , i want to confirm wether it checks the connection automatically inside every controller or during login only ??

Comment: have u invoked  the plugin into your project??

Comment: yes it will will check for every sec when ever the app is opened or trying to open....u need to place that in app.js so it wont care about your controller....if u want to use it in a paricular controller....make the connection value with rootScope and use it in your controoler