# Cordova Ionic App - check for the internet connection

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, asynchronous, ionic-framework

I've completed my newsreader app, it just works => hurray, apart from the internet checks. When the device is not connected to the internet, the app doesn't notify the user about the fact.

I have the internet check working, I just want to connect it up to every single request, so the app doesn't break if the connection was to go down while using it.

I am kind of new to the async way of doing things in Ionic, and I have a very straight question: Is there a way to make sure the device is connected to the internet before executing the request? Believe me, I've tried interceptors, and I can't seem to get it to work.

The idea is this: if the app finds out, that the device is not connected to the internet (Wi-Fi turned off, or Mobile Data turned off, the whole extent of internet check), it uses `$ionicPopup` to notify the user. Two buttons: "Refresh", "Close". Upon clicking "Refresh", the internet check is performed again, until the connection is on. During that time, the request is held. Clicking "Close" closes the dialog and the request gets rejected (`.reject()`).

A perfect solution would be a `while()` loop and a blocking `$ionicPopup`, but the `$ionicPopup` we all love is asynchronous. Dang it.

Any ideas? I'm sure it's peanuts for an experienced Angular dev. Thanks!

Comment: here is my previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305800/display-connection-error-messages-in-ionic-framework/38306129#38306129

Comment: Check for `network plugin` with that you can check for internet availability. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information __OR__ you can add listener for that.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the question. I forgot to mention, that the whole internet check works, I just want to "wire" it up to every single request, so the app doesn't break if the connection was to go down while using it.

Comment: @Sa E Chowdary I have difficulty understanding the answer. Are you suggesting to broadcast the event? And to perform the check in the HTTP interceptor? Thanks.

Comment: just add the plugin and paste the code in app.js.it will checks for connection  every sec and displays alerts on disable and enable of connection.write your code based on this value

Comment: OK, now I understand, it's the functionality of the plugin. Right. But: I don't want to bother people with that, I only want to notify them when they refresh the news, or get some info from the internet. Could you help me there, or give a general direction? Thanks!